# cocoa: know the position of the app icon in the dock

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, dock

I need to show a special menu when the dock icon is hovered. In order to do this I need to find a way to get the coordinate of the app icon in the dock.

Do you know how I can get this info?

Thanks and regards,

Answer (score 2):

Expanding the answer of Mike Abdullah: have a start with http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Carbon/Conceptual/customizing_docktile/concepts/dockconcepts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000986-CH2-TPXREF103

Greetings

Answer (score 0):

There is no public API for this. File a request asking for it. In the meantime don't attempt it. Look at a custom dock item menu instead.